# remember me symfony2 cookie deleting when closing the browser

Tags: symfony, cookies, authentication, remember-me

I want to add a "remember me" to my login form.

I've done everuthing like in the symfony2 documentation

here is my security.yml file:

```
remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
```

And i have added this checkbox in my login form :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" />
```

when i log in to my account, the cookie is created, but when i close my browser and come back, i don't have remember me cookie anymore

anyone see where is the problem ?

thanks for your answers

Comment: did you check your browser configuration? Many browsers can be configured to delete cookies after one session.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inspecting the response headers to make sure you're getting a validly-formed `Set-Cookie` header? Specifically the `expires` component?

Here's one for a Symfony2 site I've got (with the actual value greatly shortened for purposes of pasting here with legibility)

```
Set-Cookie:REMEMBERME=SldUXEV1Z; expires=Tue, 29-Oct-2013 20:13:22 GMT; path=/; httponly
```

I have the `lifetime` set at 86400 (24 hours) and insce I *just* logged in, this looks correct.

I used Chrome's dev tools to inspect the headers